# Run terminal process as background process

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

I need to have this local php file served as a wrapper but I don't want to always have to keep the terminal minimized. Is there a way I can just run this in the background and shut it down later.

```
php -S localhost:9000
```

Comment: Should be able to just add ` &` to the end but I don't know if that's really the answer here...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what sort of scripts you need to run.. For services and the like you should use upstart. But for a user script these should be launched as session scripts by gnome! Have a look under System > Preferences > Startup Applications.

On a side note if you need some scripts to be run on terminal login you can add them to the .bash_login file in your home directory.

For 14.04 and older
A simple command (one which doesn't need to remain running) could use an Upstart job like:

```
start on startup
task
exec /path/to/command
```

Save this in a .conf file in /etc/init (if you need it to run as root when the system boots up), or in ~/.config/upstart (if you need it to run as your user when you log in).

This is the reference from ask ubuntu for more details :
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up&ved=2ahUKEwi92pGb87roAhUQ3KQKHYvxA5QQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2ui3ojf99Mo6aQXOBOj06K

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` to run the command in the background.

### Killing it

By running the program in the background you are giving a process id. You can manually take note of it and kill it later.

However, you can make your life easier by storing the pid to a file with:

`php -S localhost:9000 & echo $$! > background.program.pid`

And later kill with:

`kill $(shell cat background.program.pid)`

*I use this pattern quite extensively.*